# TinyMCE escapes FreeMarker tags

Tags: html, tinymce, wysiwyg, freemarker

I use [TinyMCE 4](https://www.tinymce.com/) as a WYSIWYG editor for HTML pages. But when I use [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) tag idioms like `<#if condition>`, `<#else>` in TinyMCE, they get mangled when I go from "code view" (simple textarea) to the "design view" (WYSIWYG).

For example if I write HTML in a simple textarea (Code view)

```
<#if x == 1>
  x is 1
<#else>
  x is not 1
</#if>
```

and then toggle to editor and back to Code view, it becomes:

```
&lt;#if x == 1&gt;
    x is 1
&lt;#else/&gt;
    x is not 1
&lt;/#if&gt;
```

As you can see FreeMarker tags are getting escaped in the toggling.

**Q1:** Is there a way to configure TinyMCE to handle these tags so that when I toggle back-and-forth between the editor and the Code view the markup remains consistent?
**Q2:** Or (saying the same thing in a different way) does TinyMCE have support for FreeMarker?

---

What have I tried so far?

- I've used the [alternative (square bracket) syntax](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html).
  But I've encountered different problems since `[#tag]...[/#tag]` is treated as plain text by TinyMCE.
- I've tried to disable HTML validation in configuration:

  ```
  verify_html: false,
  valid_elements: '*[*]',
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to un-mangle them in a custom `freemarker.cache.TemplateLoader` implementation, which wraps your normal `TemplateLoader`. Though of course, there will be an ambiguity if the user indeed types "<#" or "</#", but I'm not sure if that's a problem in your application.

Comment: Thank you! That's a good solution, but I'd like to find a way to avoid this ambiguity if possible.

Comment: Can you please (as a TinyMCE maintainer) confirm that there's no way to specify FreeMarker tags as allowed HTML tags with means of TinyMCE configuration?